I can't find a recent version of numpy
I'm in ubuntu 20.04, been trying to install a more recent version of numpy after realising I had 1.24.4 but whenever I try to update it with
pip3 install --upgrade numpy

It keeps giving me this message
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/myusername/Desktop/Vision_artificial/VAA/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.24.4)

Now granted this happens in a virtual enviroment but it also happens whenever I try to update it outside of the VENV so I don't know what else to do

can you type ls -ls /usr/bin/python* and say what it says?

You are using Python 3.8. NumPy 1.24 is the last version that supports it so pip can only upgrade your NumPy up to 1.24.4 but not higher.
For higher versions of NumPy you need higher versions of Python.
From https://numpy.org/news/ : For NumPy 1.25 you need Python 3.9-3.11, for NumPy 1.26 and 2.0 you need Python 3.9-3.12, for NumPy 2.1 you need Python 3.10-3.13.

https://numpy.org/doc/1.25/release/1.25.0-notes.html could be cited as a source "The Python versions supported in this release are 3.9-3.11." The news page (https://numpy.org/news/) also shows that 1.24.4 was the last to mention python 3.8 support

Please take a look at the release notes of NumPy 1.24 which helps with compatibility. Based on release note, Python version 3.8-3.11 is supported by 1.24 version.
Release note: https://numpy.org/doc/2.0/release/1.24.0-notes.html
Python 3.8 is compatible with NumPy ver. 1.16.5 and later
Consider upgrading Python version following pip if you wanted to use higher version of NumPy.
